# How do I count the number of unique names belonging to each organization in excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to count how many people are in each organization. The data is structured like this:

```
Name    Organization  Task Completed  
name1    org1         task1  
name1    org1         task2   
name2    org1         task1  
name2    org1         task2  
name3    org2         task2
```

What I want is

```
Organization    # of people in organization  
org1            2  
org2            1
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array formula in G2 and drag down

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$6=$F2,MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$A$2:$A$6,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

You enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then curly braces should appear as seen in image.

Data:

[image: Formula]

Answer (score 0):

You can add two columns on top of the name and organization columns, say 'people' and 'org'.

Then highlight the new table selecting the people and org range (do not include the headers) and create a pivot table in a new worksheet.

In the pivot table fields, leave organization column as the rows and move the persons or 'people' column to the summation values area. The resulting table will have unique organization names with the count of people as a final table.

The result is like so:

```
Row Labels  Count of name
org1        4
org2        1
Grand Total 5
```

Comment: When you say add two columns on top, do you mean rows?

Comment: I meant add headers to each column in the original data. So above name put people, and above Organization put org. This is just to find our way around in the table.